# Calculated Column in Quick BI

Tags: cloud, analytics, business-intelligence, alibaba-cloud

I am facing an issue in creating a calculated column in Quick BI. During the creation of the Calculated column, it creates the column without any errors but when I click refresh to see the data it throws a seahawk query error.

[Creating a Calculated Column in Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN3UY.png)
[After clicking a refresh button to see the data in Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpuao.png)

Answer (score 0):

I Hope these 2 Options will help you to resolve this error.

- This type of errors appears when dealing with a spreadsheet that was created using an earlier version of excel.

  **Solution:**
  Try to create the spreadsheet in latest version of Excel.
- Probably above problem comes when you have calculated field items in your pivot data field.

  **Solution:**
  To avoid it you will have to modify the calculated fields used in pivots, just retype whatever fields used and their formula likewise you add new fields in pivot table and modify them.